# Android Gradle KeyFactorySpi is defined multiple times

Tags: android, gradle

I'm moving an old project over into a new Android Studio project - but I currently get this error:

```
Type org.gradle.internal.impldep.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.edec.KeyFactorySpi$X448 is defined multiple times:
/Users/user/.gradle/caches/8.1.1/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-api-8.1.1.jar:org/gradle/internal/impldep/META-INF/versions/11/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/edec/KeyFactorySpi$X448.class,
/Users/user/.gradle/caches/8.1.1/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-api-8.1.1.jar:org/gradle/internal/impldep/META-INF/versions/15/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/edec/KeyFactorySpi$X448.class
```

Why are there two versions of this within the Gradle jar? I've tried clearing the cache folder and downloading different Gradle versions, but this problem persists. How might I track down what code/library is using these classes?